# jQuery If this image is found on page add this meta tag?

Tags: jquery, image, find

I am trying to add rich snippets to a dynamic image that displays stars. The only thing my shopping cart writes is this image so I have to find what image is being displayed then add the proper meta tag.

So if the image being displayed is 1stars.gif I have to write:

```
<meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="1" />
```

and if the image being displayed is 5stars.gif I have to write:

```
<meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="5" />
```

Here is the UPDATED full example:

```
<span id="rateitnow">
{module_ratingrank,images/icons/stars}
<meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="" />
</span>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
$('#rateitnow meta').attr('content', $('#rateitnow').find('img:first').attr('src').substr(0,1));
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#rate-me meta').attr('content', $('#rate-me').find('img:first').attr('src').substr(0,1));
```

Comment: Wow, ty for the fast response. I don't see how this would write a specific meta tag if a specific image is being displayed in that div ID?

Comment: In your example there is no img tag

Comment: Tested it and it works : <span id="rateitnow">
     <img src="3stars.gif" />
     <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="3" />
    </span>

Comment: Also it should be $(document).ready(function()  instead of jQuery(document).ready

Comment: I should mention that the span id looked like this before running the jQuery : <span id="rateitnow"> <img src="3stars.gif" /> <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="" /> </span> - If you want to add the whole meta line then in this case, it would be : $('#rate-me').prepend('<meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="'+$('#rate-me').find('img:first').attr('src').substr(0,1)+'" />');